# How to download Go on a pixelbook/chromebook/Linux(debian)

Tags: linux, go, download, chromebook

I use a Pixelbook for programming, and it uses Linux(Debian) (A beta version). It is however quite complicated to download certain software, and I was wondering if anyone could help. I am downloading Go, for Linux 64bit. I don't know what to write in the terminal in order to unpack it and open it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a detailed guide for [ChromeOS Installation on Golang Wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/ChromeOS). It contains all commands you need to type in terminal.